Dropdown menu issues on a mobile
Having a problem with menu items (which have sub-elements) displaying correctly at mobile size. All seems to work fine on desktop  and the submenu items appear when you hover over the main navigation item. At mobile though it is not possible to expand the navigation menu items which have sub-items.
Struggling to work out where I've gone wrong with this one. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions offered.


  <!-- Navbar Links -->
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse page-scroll navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- About dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="about.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="350" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="visit-pilar.html">Visit Pilar</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="pepito.html">Meet Pepito <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- Learning dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="learning.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="350" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Learning <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="spanish-for-children.html">Spanish for Children</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="spanish-for-students.html">Spanish for Students</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="spanish-for-adults.html">Spanish for Adults</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- / Learning dropdown -->
      <li>
        <a href="companies.html">Companies <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="prices.html">Prices <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- Projects dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="projects.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="350" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="project-spanish-study-buddies.html">Spanish Study buddies</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="project-kimbo.html">Project Kimbo</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="project-wcj-girls-football.html">WCJ Girls Football</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- / Projects dropdown -->
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact <span class="sr-only"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- / .nav .navbar-nav -->
  </div>
  <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
<!-- / .navbar -->




Probably because in mobile you can't hover over elements instead you can click on them to expand dropdown menus.

Sorry - I wasn't clear. Clicking on the arrow in the mobile menu doesn't seem to work in expanding the menu item

The provided code snippet cannot reproduce the described error. More clarification is needed. Associate the appropriate CDN libraries for the code to work properly. Perhaps you are using Bootstrap but didn't mention it. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Furthermore, the provided code snippet contains a typo. There is a closing </nav> tag at the end, but it does not have an opening tag.

The problem is that the dropdowns are not expanding on mobile because the necessary Bootstrap JavaScript and jQuery libraries for handling dropdown interactions are missing. Adding these libraries ensures that the data-toggle="dropdown" attribute functions correctly on mobile devices.
please try and change according to your design


  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="about.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          About
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="about.html">About Us</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="visit-pilar.html">Visit Pilar</a>
        </div>
      </li>




@user:24816780  Would I need to change the id tag in your suggestion above? I tried adding your code and replacing "navbarDropDownMenuLink' with "about". It didn't seem to work but maybe because I am looking at it on a local server. Perhaps I also need to add the missing Bootstrap JavaScript and jQuery libraries as well? Not sure how / where to find / add those?

@alex_cissokho Please provide code with the Bootstrap version. or just past this code in your file and see if it's working or not .

I checked the Bootstrap version and it's old: 3.3.5. So ip updated it but that's thrown alot of the site design out so thinking I need to keep the older version of Bootstrap for now but get the site re-built sometime soon.
